# Return a value from Map

Tags: java, syntax

I have Map in Java

```
Map<String, List<String>> Collections;
```

String - a parents to ExpandtableList

List  -a children to Expandtable List

```
Example Values 
 <"12" , "5,6,7,8">
 <"15" , "4,6,2,8">
 <"17" , "1,6,7,8">
 <"8" , "5,6,6,8">
```

I'd like to get second parent and atribute to temporary String variable.(it is a "17") How can i refer to 2-nd parent and return value ?

Comment: question is not clear. You need to get the value of key "17"?

Comment: I don't understand your question..

Comment: When i used this map to populate Expandtable List, and I;ll click on any item. Then function return me a number of parent and child for example parent:2 , child:1. This is a number but in Map i have id_parent, and id_child, In Fact parent is"17" and child is "6"

Answer (score 0):

There is no ordering in `HashMap`. If you want to focused on Order with `Map` you should use `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Ok my Map is LinkedHashMap now Collection = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>(); How can i get value 2nd parent now?

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead of HashSet. `LinkedHashMap` will maintain the insertion order.

Comment: Ok my Map is LinkedHashMap Collection = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>(); How can i get value 2nd parent now?

Comment: @user2976675 do you expect this collection.get("17");

Comment: I need  exactly inversely. collection.get(2) And i'd like to return 17. But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain an order in a `Map`, your usual choice would be a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). With a linked hash map, you do however still not have direct access to an entry by its index. You would need to write a helper function:

```
static List<String> indexList(LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> map, int index) {
  int i = 0;
  for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(i++ == index) {
      return entry.getValue();
    }
  }
  throw new IndexOutOfBoundException();
}
```

When using maps that point to a list, you might also be interested in using Guava's [`Multimap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424289/return-a-value-from-map#20424333).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want "17" then you can just write map.get("17") to get the List.

Java doesnt keep track of the order here as it uses a `Set` to store the data. map.keySet() will return you a set you can iterate through.

You can HOPE that 17 falls under the natural ordering that Java does and do something like this.

```
 HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
 int count = 0;
 for (String key : map.keySet()) {
   count++;
   if (count == 2)
     return map.get(key);
 }
```